# Where to deploy zip file on Apache tomcat 7 to be available for download?

Tags: tomcat7

I am creating a zip file through my app deployed on apache tomcat 7. I want to make that zip available for download to the users. Where shall I place my zip on tomcat server to be available for download or Can I store my zips on some drive and map them through tomcat to be available for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 ways to it.
Option 1: Put your zip or any file under webapps folder e.g. /webapps/test/hello.zip. Putting zip there can be accessed by `http://<host:port>/test/hello.zip`

Option 2: You can map any directory on your file system accessible via tomcat. To do this you need to configure server.xml at $Tomcat_home/conf/server.xml
Add this new  tag under  tag.

```
<Context path="/test" docBase="complete_path_of_dir_contaning_zip_file">< / Context >
```

Now zip can be accessed in same way `http://<host:port>/test/hello.zip`

Answer (score 0):

If you have a database, I'd store the file as a blob in a documents table, and build a servlet that is able to handle the file download. It's easy to implement. The database table should record the blob, the mime type and the name of the file.
In this way, you always have your file available (if you store the file in your webapp folder, and redeploy the war, your file will be dropped).

Comment: I don't want to use database and I also don't want to store it in my webapp folder for the same reason you said. Need to store it somewhere on my disk and map it through tomcat.

Comment: You can create a folder with write&read privileges (to the user you are running tomcat) and store in it. For example /my_app_docs (outside tomcat installation), and handle from your servlet this absolute path.