# How to deploy .exe file on Tomcat and make it downloadable

Tags: java, tomcat

I tried to use "Option 1" from the answer here: [Where to deploy zip file on Apache tomcat 7 to be available for download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845687/where-to-deploy-zip-file-on-apache-tomcat-7-to-be-available-for-download)
I put my .exe into folder named "executable" inside "webapp" folder and opened
 http:// localhost:8080 /executable/***.exe 
in the browser but it shows 404.

What could be the problem and is it a right way to deploy a file for downloading on Tomcat?

Comment: ... you actually started Tomcat, right?

Comment: Could be your web framework is restricting to download anything from server, Try just .txt instead of .exe and try again.

Comment: or the frameworks wants to handle the whole app from the root path. A look inside your web.xml might help.

Comment: Yes, I actually started Tomcat.
Tried .txt instead of .exe, still 404 response.
Root path is webapp folder.

Comment: @user2246018 You might want to try adding a simple WEB-INF/web.xml so it becomes a minimalistic web application. Then start the Tomcat manager web application and check if it actually lists your executable webapp in there. And just to be sure: if you go to localhost:8080 you see the tomcat welcome page?